# WPF application run background even if we close the application,can any one suggest me

Tags: c#, wpf

I'have build an wpf application and I want my application to be run in background even if I close the app

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have build an login page and dashboard page and I want my app to run background even If close

Answer (score 2):

If you close the app, your app will obviously not run in the background, or in the foreground, or anywhere. Because it has been closed. What you mean is that you want your app to run in the background even if you close ***the main window*** of the app.

First, you will have to add a handler for the `Closing` event of your main window, and in that handler you will need to set `e.Cancel = true;` to cancel the close event.  Then, your application will just need to destroy or hide the main window. And voila, your application continues running without a main window.

Or, as Sir Rufo says in a comment, modify the `Application.ShutdownMode` property so that your application does not close when its last window is closed.

Comment: Why so complicated? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.shutdownmode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @SirRufo thanks for the suggestion, I added it to the answer.